# Python selenium phantom js

Tags: python, selenium, testing, dropdown

Having problem with Python Selenium and Phantom JS.
Problem : setting driver to Phantom JS

```html
<div class="ProfileTweet-action ProfileTweet-action--more js-more-ProfileTweet-actions">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="ProfileTweet-actionButton u-textUserColorHover dropdown-toggle js-dropdown-toggle" type="button" aria-haspopup="true">
  
  </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu is-autoCentered">
      <div class="js-first-tabstop" tabindex="0"></div>
      <div class="dropdown-caret">
        <div class="caret-outer"></div>
        <div class="caret-inner"></div>
      </div>
      <ul tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu-1" aria-hidden="false">
        <li class="js-actionDelete" role="presentation">
          <button type="button" class="dropdown-link" role="menuitem">Удалить  </button>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <div class="js-last-tabstop" tabindex="0"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Actual problem is here ---- after clicking on this class

```
  ProfileTweet-action ProfileTweet-action--more js-more-ProfileTweet-actions
```

code below

```
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.IconContainer").click()
```

is not doing the trick but when driver is set to Firefox it works as expected
 .
Is there anything I am missing? Thanks

**Edit 1**
For sake of simplicity I excluded all elements and left only button which opens dropdown 
here is the code

```
 <button class="ProfileTweet-actionButton u-textUserColorHover dropdown-toggle js-dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu-0">   </button>
```

Problem here is **PahntomJS** **not DOM itself**   because as I mentioned above script works as expected with **firefox** driver

Comment: Do any errors come?

Comment: Use Chrome Developer Tools and try to find the element by xpath.

Comment: no errors at all I save as a screenshot an I see that dropdown is not opened

Comment: path is correct as I use firefox as a driver and it works as expected

Comment: your HTML doesn't have IconContainer div. Please correct it